# Cannot run Maui project .net6 in Visual studio 2022 version 17.8.1

Tags: android, visual-studio, maui

I updated visual studio from 17.4 to 17.8.1
When i run my Maui project (using .NET6) It had an error:

> C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\32.0.509\targets\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.RuntimeConfig.targets(38,5):
> error MSB4036: The "RuntimeConfigParserTask" task was not found. Check
> the following: 1.) The name of the task in the project file is the
> same as the name of the task class. 2.) The task class is "public" and
> implements the Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask interface. 3.) The task
> is correctly declared with  in the project file, or in the
> *.tasks files located in the "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64" directory.

I reinstalled maui workload and added a global.json

> {
> "sdk": {
> "version": "6.0.416",
> "rollForward": "latestMinor"
> }

but this error was still occurred.

**Note that: i change TargetFrameworks from net6 to net8 in csproj file, it works.**

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you manually installed .NET 6 SDK? It gets removed with the update of VS. I am troubleshooting the same issue right now, will update if I find a solution.

Comment: I ended up trying quite a few things including having two versions of VS installed side-by-side. None of that worked, but I was able to revert my existing VS install to 17.7.6 which works fine. If you are using VS Community you might be able to do this using the VS Installer under More. Otherwise you can download whatever you would like [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-history)

Comment: you mean it works fine for .NET6 and .NET8

Comment: No, just works for .NET 6. VS 17.8 added .NET 8. So I will be using a different machine for .NET 8 builds at the moment, I do hope to find a solution that allows both, but am not too hopeful.

Comment: The last working version that I found is **17.4.4**. I ended up adding VS Pro to my Azure account because it annoyed me so much swapping between computers. I've been holding off on updating to .Net 8 as the update would be fairly time consuming.